# Mapreduce, HDFS input, Hive table output

Tags: mapreduce, hive, hdfs

I would like to write a mapreduce job to do the following:

1. Read HDFS file.
2. Verify read record already exists in table (Hive/Hbase).
3. If it exists, perform update operation. If it does not exists, write/insert data into the table (Hive/Hbase).

Above process would be repeated daily.

Question:

1. Is it possible to implement above logic with Hive?
2. How can write MR job? any example to implement the above logic?

Answer (score 1):

There is more than a way to do what you want.
Yes, you can do the whole thing in hive.
Hive has some SerDes which allow you to access Hbase, so you can use also this from hive.

Your MR job is composed only by mappers which does the work; anyway, since hive can do it, I don't think is a good idea to write a MR job.
Perhaps the fast way to build your MR job is using the utility stream, you can write your mapper in any language you like.

If both cases, using hive or a small MR job, you can put the job under oozie and get it running on daily basis.

Comment: Thankyou soo much for your inputs. I need to perform some Data manipulation before i insert the data into Hive/Hbase table. Is it possible to perform data manipulation in Hive?                                                                                     What do you mean by utility stream?

Comment: There is a jar which is able to scan your  file using your custom mapper and reducer. It could  be a good and easy way to start writing simple map reducer jobs. Google for hadoop streaming

Comment: Thank you. i will search on google.  I need to perform some Data manipulation before i insert the data into Hive/Hbase table. Is it possible to perform data manipulation in Hive? any suugestions on this question?

Comment: [hadoop streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html) using this you can solve a lot of simple problems without need to program MapReduce jobs with with java.